# ¿Como cargar un imageView con la propiedad de un objeto bean en android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Hola espero poder explicarme y que me puedan ayudar, tengo esta clase donde tiene un objeto bean noticias con propiedad noticia. newsIconUrl que contiene una URL y necesito mostrar una imagen en un imageview con esa url mi problema consiste en pasar esa propiedad a una variable global para después ocuparla en los métodos para mostrarla en el imageview o que otra solución proponen gracias de ante mano.

```
public class NoticiaDescripcion extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5,tv6;
    ImageView foto;
    public String imagen;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.noticia_layout);
        NewsBean noticia = (NewsBean)getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("noticia");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), noticia.newsIconUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv1.setText(noticia.newsTitle);
        tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pieFoto);
        tv2.setText(noticia.pieFoto);
        tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lugar);
        tv3.setText(noticia.lugar);
        tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.autor);
        tv4.setText(noticia.autorNota);
        tv5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seccion);
        tv5.setText(noticia.newsSeccion);
        tv6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto);
        tv6.setText(noticia.texto);
        foto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
}
}
```

Comment: Hoy día no. -.- Con todo el respeto, pero es un castigo de leerlo así. Si puedes darnos la cortesía de usar puntuación aun que sea básica, me tomo el tiempo de leer tu pregunta. ¿Bienvenido a StaclOverflow!

Comment: La clase NewsBean es una clase personalizada que tú creaste, es de algún servicio Api o de qué cosa

Comment: Creo que es importante agregues tu bean: NewsBean  para saber que método accede a tomar la imagen @BryanAntonioSmithAltobelli

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar picasso

Basta con añadirla a tu archivo build.gradle de tu modulo

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

después hacer uso de la librería de la siguiente manera:

```
Picasso.with(NoticiaDescripcion.this).load(noticia.newsIconUrl).into(foto);
```

**Más información:**

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

Para cargar la imagen debes obtener el url del bean, como ejemplo suponiendo que el método para obtener el url, accediendo a la propiedad `newsIconUrl` es `getUrl()`, obtendrías la imagen y para cargar la imagen puede usar **[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)** o **[Glide](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)**, un ejemplo usando Picasso:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.noticia_layout);
       NewsBean noticia = (NewsBean)getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("noticia");
...
...
        //Obtiene la url del bean.
        String urlImagen = noticia.getUrl();
        //Obtiene la referencia del ImageView.
        foto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        //Agrega la imagen al ImageView. Picasso.with(this).load(urlImagen).into(foto);
}
```